# LinkageError facing while doing spark-submit

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark

Facing the below error when we are doing a spark-submit v3.2.2. We are adding external spark-streaming-kafka-0-10 v2.12-3.1.1. When we tried to debug the issue, it looks like the slf4j-api-1.7.29 jar which is used by our application is causing the conflict.
But when we are trying to exclude the slf4j-api jar, Our application loggers are failing to initialise with error like "No appenders could be found for logger (Main Class)".
We are also using logback jars which may be using slf4j-api internally, not exactly clear about it. But this issue we have found no resolution.

> java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation in interface itable initialization: when resolving method "org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.Subscribe.org$apache$spark$internal$Logging$$log_() Lorg/slf4j/Logger;" the class loader (instance of org/apache/spark/util/ChildFirstURLClassLoader) of the current class, org/apache/spark/streaming/kafka010/Subscribe, and the class loader (instance of sun/misc/Launcher$AppClassLoader) for interface org/apache/spark/interna1/Logging have different Class objects for the type org/slf4j/Logger used in the signature at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.Consumerstrategies$. Subscribe (Consumerstrategy.scala:299

[image]